# Laravel validation rule for mathematical expression

Tags: php, regex, laravel, validation

I want to take mathematical input from users and save them in database. Then, I want to show the result of the mathematical expression. Now, I need a validation rule to check if the input is a valid mathematical expression. It need not to be very complex. Just basic addition and subtraction is enough for me.
For example, `2+4+5+8` or `5-2+4`.
I do not even need any bracket.
Can anyone give me a validation rule that works for **laravel** validator?

Comment: There are some php math packages that interprete mathematical expressions. Maybe you can try one of these? If the parsing fails, the given input is wrong. Maybe that is enough to start with?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a specific validation rule for this because I don't think Laravel includes it by default. So let's make a `php artisan make:rule Expression` and inside of it, something like that:

```php
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    $value = preg_replace('\s', '', $value);
    return preg_match("/^\d+([\+\-\*\/]{1}\d+)+$/", $value);
}
```

As you can see, I have previously removed any form of white space because it makes regex simpler while accepting cases such as: "2+5", "2 + 5", "2+ 5', "2 + 5".

Then you can just call it in your Controller like:

```php
'input' => ['required', new Expression]
```

To manage brackets, unfortunately regex won't help you. You'll have to use a kind of parser able to handle the infinite possibility of grouping expressions such as "2 + (5 * (3 / (1/2)))"). * 5)".